# Laravel (5.8) php unit make raw post request

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

To make a regular test post request one can use:

```
   // signature: json(string method,string url, array data)
   $response = $this->json("post","/api/oee/v1/statuses/log", ["data" =>$data])
```

However, the json() method expects an array as the data parameter. 
however my data needs to be a raw string:

```
{ "data": [ { "component_id": 16, "value": 265, "time": 1556520087 }, { "component_id": 16, "value": 324, "time": 1556520087 }, { "component_id": 16, "value": 65, "time": 1556520087 } ] }
```

Is there a method I can use to send a post request with the raw data?

Comment: Perhaps you could just `json_decode($data, true)` the `$data` string. Then you pass that to the `json` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode your string and pass it as an array.

```
$data = '{ "data": [ { "component_id": 16, "value": 265, "time": 1556520087 }, { "component_id": 16, "value": 324, "time": 1556520087 }, { "component_id": 16, "value": 65, "time": 1556520087 } ] }';

$response = $this->json("post","/api/oee/v1/statuses/log", [
    "data" => json_decode($data, true)
]);
```

If this is a common operation in your test suite then create a helper method in a base application test case:

```
public function jsonString($method, $uri, $data, array $headers = [])
{
    return $this->json($method, $uri, json_decode($data, true), $headers);
}
```

Or a trait would be better, something you can use only when needed, e.g:

```
trait MakesRawJsonRequests
{
    public function jsonRaw($method, $uri, $data, array $headers = [])
    {
        return $this->json($method, $uri, json_decode($data, true), $headers);
    }
}
```

Alternate naming convention: `jsonFromString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `call()` :

```
$this->call('POST', '/your/route',  [], [], [], [], 'your request body');
```